# How do I hide parts of the mesh while weight painting?

Tags: armature, weight-painting, masking

https://youtu.be/6LCPkH8XiBc

So I'm trying to do weight paints in Blender for my character that has quite a bit of overlapping mesh on the head. From what I've read you go into edit mode, select the mesh you wanna hide, then hide it with H. Which works fine. Then you're supposed to go into Weight Paint mode and turn on the paint mask. When I do this the mesh I've hidden in Edit mode does not go hidden.

Alternatively, I've been told you can just straight up select faces in Paint Mask and hide them, which works until I put my brush on the model to do paint weights and the hidden parts of the mesh just come back.

This has been frustrating and I've included a link to a youtube video showing exactly what I've done. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The best and safest method is to select the vertices you want to hide, press P to separate them, press \ to go to isolation mode, do all weight paint you need on both objects, then select the separated part, shift select the base mesh (last), and press Ctrl J to rejoin them: weights and names will be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the reason it's not working is that I'm on 2.9 and it is broken on 2.9. Went back to 2.82 and it's working just fine now.